# How to pass object as props to previous react component when navigating back with browser back button (react, react router )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using **react-router** for navigation in my app.

To pass some data from current component to other component while navigating using `Link` we use:

```
this.props.history.push('/other-page', { id: 7, color: 'green', .... }))
```

How can I pass data(object) to the previous component from current component when **browser back button is clicked** ?

**PS**: 
I saw some solutions where it is suggested to pass some data with **query string**
but I don't want to use it because I have to **pass a big object** with many properties.

So it possible with react-router ? Our I would have do that with state in some outer component or use Redux store for shared data ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have two questions for giving you a better answer.
1. When you click "back button" your child component unmounts?
2. Can you pass props from your parent component to the child?

Comment: 3. Do you use class components or functional?

Comment: 1. after i click back button, browser navigates to different route(url) so current component unmounts and new component based on route is loaded.. 2. Yes. but i want the user to click back button and go through what data they saw. and if i use this approach then it wont pe possible

Comment: 3.Class component

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use some storage like reducer if some data could be used in different components. It is much better, then pass data through query params or callbacks. You can use [`react-redux`](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) or migrate from class components to functional and use [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook.

If you need some example, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for response. I know this approach :)

Comment: @AMITKUMAR you have unaccepted an answer. My answer did not help you?

Comment: sir your answer is correct, but I want to do the way I mentioned... pass object through react-router.....